# autocmd does not detect *.ott files

Tags: vim, file-type, autocmd

I'd like to have syntax highlighting on files with the `.ott` extension (using [ott-vim](https://github.com/psosera/ott-vim)), but I am not getting any colors when opening a file, even though `filetype=ott` is set. Re-setting `set filetype=ott` manually does enable the colors again.

Oddly enough, I also get colors on file opening when I change the extension in `ftdetect/ott.vim` to something other than `*.ott`.

Is there something special about the `*.ott` extension, or some clash with another file format?

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ott set filetype=ott
" a.ott does not get highlighted
" Replace *.ott with *.ot, then a.ot gets highlighted
```

Comment: The plugin seems to work fine in 9.0.54, 8.2.4113, and 8.2.3455 so the autocommand in `ftdetect/ott.vim` is fine. Your problem is thus elsewhere and you should use their issue tracker.

Comment: I don't doubt  the cause could be specific to my config and to ott, but advice on how to debug autocmd issues would still be helpful, which doesn't have to be specific to my situation. If I knew how to troubleshoot this I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. "How to troubleshoot possible autocommand-related issues?" is a very different question than the one you asked.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a conflict with the `zipPlugin` that is distributed with vim (`/usr/share/vim/current/plugin/zipPlugin.vim`), and which recognizes a `.ott` file as a zip archive. Hacky fix to remove that extension from those recognized by `zipPlugin`:

```
" ~/.vimrc
let g:zipPlugin_ext='*.zip'
```